# CSS Print page footer only on last page

Tags: html, css, printing

First of all, I've searched SO and there is no working solution

I have some long content, and I want to have footer only on last page. 
I tired:

1)

```
.footer{       
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If puts footer at the end of first page only.

2) As old answers suggest

```
@page :last
```

But `:last` doesn't exist (as I see from old answer it existed).

3) Normal footer, sure it is shown on the end of all pages.

How can I achieve this, footer only on last page ?

Comment: Since the answers don't provide a solution: Did you find a work-around or did you solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately. We changed design a little and it worked for us

Comment: May you share how you changed your design in order for it to work? Perhaps it's an appropiate alternative for others (including me) as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try wrapping your header and content in a container with `min-height:100vh`. This should push your footer to the very bottom.

```css
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1> The Header </h1>
  <p> The Content </p>
</main>
<footer>
  The Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Nope, not working at all. When there is 1 page, the section takes full page and footer goes to another, and is not footer at all, just beginning of a second page.

Comment: @MishaAkopov do you have a screenshot of what that looks like?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and found a working solution.

I inserted a `<div id="spacer">` in front of my footer and gave it `page-break-after: always`. That made my footer appear right on top of a new empty page following my content. I then gave my footer `margin-top: -130px` (or whatever height your footer has). That made is go back one page and placed it right at the bottom of my last page, as desired.

There are 2 downsides:

- My generated pdf file has an empty page at the end
- I have to make sure that there is enough space for the footer to appear

Nonetheless this is a (seemingly only?) way to place a footer only on the last page when printing html.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me with Puppeteer (Chrome/Chromium), but the `.footer` element must not be nested in another element, it must be placed directly in the `body` tag:

```
.footer {
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: -130px;
  page-break-before: always;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap the footer with the last page container. Treat the footer as just another div.

Comment: Not a solution at all. The 2 divs come one after another.

Comment: Show your screenshot of the page along with the html code